# Background image not showing in HTML or SharePoint and not sure what issue is

Tags: html, css, sharepoint

Ok I rewrote the code several times and change the image location a couple of times. For some odd reason the image will not show and I'm not sure what the issue is. I am new to coding as far as a website and style sheets. I've included some of my code. I could not include all of my links.

```
.container{ /*background-image:url(https://gamepoint.scientificgames.com/sites/busdept/gp/PublishingImages/GP%20site/SG%20Global%20Proposal%20Logo%202015_no%20cube-01.jpg); margin:0px; background-attachment:fixed; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center; background-image:url(https://gamepoint.scientificgames.com/sites/busdept/gp/PublishingImages/GP%20site/SG%20Global%20Proposal%20Logo%202015_no%20cube-01.jpg); background-size:100% auto; background-repeat:no-repeat; height:100% auto; width:100%; margin:0 auto;*/ border:#5F5F5F thin; }

/*@import url(//fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);*/ 

.navigation{width:1325px; height:103px;} 

.maincontent{height:955px;} 

.maintable{margin:0 auto; line-height:1px; width:700px;} 

.maintabletext{font-family: &#39;Source Sans Pro&#39;, sans-serif; color:white; font-size:24px; text-align:center;} 

.mainfiller{color:white; font-size:18px; font-family: &#39;Open Sans&#39;, sans-serif; text-align:center; line-height:25px; } 

h1.maintabletext { font-family: &#39;Open Sans&#39;, sans-serif; font-size: 72px; font-weight:700; color:white; text-align:center; }
```

Answer (score 0):

The background image applied in `.container` seems to be commented out?

Tried to clean up below.

```
.container{ margin:0px; background-attachment:fixed; background-repeat:no-repeat; background-position:center center; background-image:url("https://gamepoint.scientificgames.com/sites/busdept/gp/PublishingImages/GP%20site/SG%20Global%20Proposal%20Logo%202015_no%20cube-01.jpg"); background-size:100% auto; background-repeat:no-repeat; height:100%; width:100%; margin:0 auto; border:#5F5F5F thin; }
```

Comment: I did not even notice that. Originally when I coded it, that wasn't there. I've made the change.

Comment: @KeonEdge How did it go? What text editor are you using to write code with?

Comment: I was using a content editor within sharepoint and just editing the html source. I wish i could include the other links but it will not allow me too.